# How boundedly generated is $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, matrices, kt.k-theory-and-homology, geometric-group-theory

The group $G = \mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ is known to be ***boundedly generated***, that is, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and $g_1, \dots, g_m \in G$ such that we have the following equality of sets: $$ G = \langle g_1 \rangle \cdots \langle g_m \rangle. $$

Is there an elementary/accessible proof of this fact? I would like to have a reference to a proof.

How small can we take $m$ to be?

Is it possible to take $m = 8$?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundedly_generated_group) cites a 1984 paper by Carter and Keller, *Elementary expressions for unimodular matrices*. They determine that for $G = \mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$ ($n > 2$) you can take elementary matrices for all the $g_i$ and get an upper bound $m \le \frac12(3n^2-n) + 36$.

Comment: Section 4.1 gives the proof. It uses Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions. http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf

Comment: Another exposition of the elementary proof can be found in a paper by Adian and Mennicke http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/s0218196792000220

Comment: $m=2$ is clearly impossible: you can't even generate the invertible matrices mod 2 this way, because each $\left|\langle g_i\rangle\right| \leq 7$ and $7 \times 7 < 168$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies This is great! I had some other argument in mind, regarding the possible eiganvalues of a product $g^ih^j$.

Comment: You're welcome.  I see that you've now changed "$m=2$" to "$m=5$".
In fact I think any $m<8$ can be excluded by a $p$-adic dimension argument:
for any $p$, each $\langle g_i \rangle$ is contained in 
the union of finitely many one-dimensional $p$-adic patches,
so their product has dimension at most $m$,
and thus cannot exhaust ${\rm SL}_3({\bf Z})$
beause this group's closure in ${\rm SL}_3({\bf Z}_p)$
has dimension $8$.

Comment: @Noam, do you have a good reference for such things (the interplay between $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$)?

Comment: Sorry, my answer to "do you have a good reference for X?" 
is almost always "no"...  This is the kind of thing where
it feels easier to figure it out directly than to look it up
in the literature.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies this is a very interesting argument!!! Let me please increase $m$ again.

Comment: @algorithmshark even though your comment has been upvoted by many, there seems to be a delicate point: the bound you present is one which allows the (elementary) matrices to appear in arbitrary order in the product, and it clearly disagrees with the definition given in the question. It is clear that a bound (for my definition) can be deduced from the bound you gave, but it may become highly nonoptimal. Reading the proof referenced by Ian Agol though, I get an impression that the order of elementary operations is independent of the matrix in question, so the bound is probably correct.